# save var_dump into text file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, var-dump

I have the php code for sql query

```html
<?
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "1";

$link= connecttodb($server,$username,$password);

function connecttodb($server,$username,$password)
{

    $rez=fopen("test.txt","ab");
    if ($link=mysql_connect ("$server","$username","$password",TRUE))
    {
        fwrite($rez,"".$server." \r\n");
     echo "Connected successfully to >> " .$server ;
  
  $result = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES');
        echo "<br>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            var_dump ($row); }
     }
    }
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);
    return $link;
?>
```

this code print my database name on the browser
how I can save the database name into text file

```html
Connected successfully to >> 127.0.0.1
array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "information_schema" ["Database"]=> string(18) "information_schema" } array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "db" ["Database"]=> string(2) "db" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "mysql" ["Database"]=> string(5) "mysql" } array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "phpmyadmin" ["Database"]=> string(10) "phpmyadmin" } array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "test" ["Database"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

Comment: If you initiate a connection to the db then you MUST know the name of the db

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: @RamRaider if you look at OP's code, he is initializing a connection to the server without specifying the schema. He is attempting to list all databases on the server that he as access to.

Comment: As @RiggsFolly said learn PDO, however the manual might seem a bit overwhelming so you could [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), it is extremely good and will have up and running in no time.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the output buffering functions to capture output and write it to a file.

```
ob_flush();
ob_start();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
file_put_contents("dump.txt", ob_get_flush());
```

Comment: `var_dump` is meant for debugging by humans, it's not meant to be parsed by programs.

Comment: please look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928140/save-var-dump-into-text-file-for-multi-server-ip-from-text-file

Comment: `serialize($myobj)` as suggested by @Matth3w is a better solution

Comment: The code in the question uses `var_dump()`. The question was about how to get the output into a file, not the format of the file.

Comment: `$str = print_r($row, true);` when true it returns a string, same with var_dump

Comment: @jscripter That only works for `print_r`, not `var_dump`.

Comment: @jscripter ty so much better

Comment: Better solution `file_put_contents('var_dump.txt',var_export($array, true));`

Answer (score 25):

Don't use var_dump for this, use serialize like so:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('vardump.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, serialize($myobj));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

To restore it, you can use unserialize($filecontents); by reading it back in from the file.

Comment: Simple, excellent idea. There is also `print_r()` to create a string from any variable which may be easier to read than serialized data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "1";

$link= connecttodb($server,$username,$password);

function connecttodb($server,$username,$password)
{

$rez=fopen("test.txt","ab");
   if ($link=mysql_connect ("$server","$username","$password",TRUE))
   {
   fwrite($rez,"".$server." \r\n");
    echo "Connected successfully to >> " .$server ;

        $result = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES');
echo "<br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
fwrite($rez, $row['DatabaseName']); }

    }

}
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);
return $link;
    ?>
```

Answer (score -3):

This should work

```
$file = 'somefile.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $some_var);
```

You may want to serialize the variable first to make it more readable.

But there are several other methods: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php