# save var_dump into text file for multi server ip from text file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, var-dump

this php code for sql query,
if I have multi sql sever into text file and I want get servers from this file.
how I can save var_dump for each sever into "serverip.txt"

```
<?

$list =file('servers.txt');
$username = "root";
$password = "1";
foreach($list as $server)
$link= connecttodb($server,$username,$password);
function connecttodb($server,$username,$password)
{

$rez=fopen("test.txt","ab");
   if ($link=mysql_connect ("$server","$username","$password",TRUE))
   {
   fwrite($rez,"".$server." \r\n");
    echo "Connected successfully to >> " .$server ;

        $result = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES');
echo "<br>";

ob_flush();
ob_start();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   var_dump($row);
    file_put_contents("$server.txt", ob_get_flush());
}


    }

}
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);
return $link;
    ?>
```

I have this error

> Warning: file_put_contents(ServerIp .txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\AppServ\www\connectdb.php on line 24

Comment: Don't. Use an *actual* encoding format like [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Don't. Use an actual encoding format like JSON. ???
how ??

Comment: try `ob_start()` and then `ob_get_clean();`

Comment: I typically dont use output buffering this way, but I think the main issue is this. `The output buffer must be started by ob_start() with PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE flag. Otherwise ob_get_flush() will not work.`  As in `ob_start(null, 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE )`

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I've had to do something similar to this before where I had to assign a variable to an `ob_` function and set it outside the conditionals. Rather than injecting the `ob_` function inside the `file_put_contents()` function.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea it could be creating a PHP warning, you know the one, I forget what it says ... lol  When you try to use the return value in a write context.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something more precise, like `print_r` would work, where it has a mode for storing the output

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    file_put_contents("$server.txt", print_r($row, true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
ob_get_flush()
```

You want

```
$var = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents("$server.txt", $var );
```

To put it all togather you would need to do this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   ob_start();
   var_dump($row);
   file_put_contents("$server.txt",ob_get_clean());
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

> Get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer ...
>   Returns the contents of the output buffer and end output buffering. If output buffering isn't active then FALSE is returned.

-Note- the `end output buffering` this is why we need to restart it `ob_start()` on each iteration of the loop.

For `ob_get_flush()`

> The output buffer must be started by ob_start() with
>   PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE flag. Otherwise ob_get_flush() will not
>   work.

That said it may not be the best approach for your goal.  As an alternative method, you can use this function

```
function getVarType( $var, $escapeHtml = true ){
    $strArg = 'unknown';
    switch ( gettype( $var ) ){
        case 'boolean':
            return ( $var ? 'true' : 'false' );
        case 'integer':
            return intval( $var );
        case 'double':
            return floatval( $var );
        case 'string':
            if( $escapeHtml ){
                $var = htmlentities( $var, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
            }

            return "'".$var."'";
        case 'resource':
            return 'Resource id #'.intval( $var );
        case 'NULL':
            return 'NULL';
        case 'array':
            return "Array";
        case 'object':
            return 'Object('.get_class( $var ).')';
        case 'unknown type':
        default:
            return'UNKNOWN TYPE';
    }
}  

 $row = array_map( 'getVarType', $row );
```

However I think in PHP 7 they reversed the Parameters for array map.  This is from an Exception/Error handling class I just wrote, you can modify it to more closely match var_dump if you want.  Currently, it's setup to match the exception stack trace printout.

By the way if you want a really killer debuggin class, you can use the one from my framework

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/EVO/Debug.php

With some small modification it may fit your needs ( perhaps a bit overkill )

This is what it outputs

```
$G = ['one'=>1, 'two' => 2, 3=>['foo', 'bar']];
EVO_Debug::dump( $G );

==================================== EVO_DEBUG::DUMP =====================================
Output from FILE[ C:\UniServerZ\www\Evo\EVO\bootstrap.php ] on LINE[ 72 ]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
array(3){
     ["one"] => int(1),
     ["two"] => int(2),
     [3] => array(2){
          [0] => string(3) "foo",
          [1] => string(3) "bar",
     },
}
==========================================================================================
```

Although you want to use

```
 EVO_Debug::export( $G );
```

It can also output private properties, and class constants.  I only post the link because it's not trivial to deal with all the possible variable types, and it doesn't help here that PHP is Non-Typed language.

Comment: good point Fred.  Also I don't think this is the best way to save the data.

Comment: I'd like to set something up myself, but TBH, I am bushed. At this time of night, my head is mush.

Comment: I have this ^ similar idea, but its setup for outputting a trimmed exception stack trace.  Basically I have a few calls in my Framework that are always the same, so I want to remove them from the stacktrace, but the exception class `getTraceAsString` is final, so no overloading it.  So I prune it down and then create my own string stack trace from the normal array version.  Basically it's a way to get a stacktrace for debugging, that is similar to the exception classes output.